# Cancel Navigating event in Xamarin Forms webview

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to open tel links in my xamarin forms application `webview` using the `Navigating` event:

```
    public async void WebViewNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Url.StartsWith("tel:"))
        {
            await Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher.OpenAsync(args.Url);
        }
    }
```

But I have two issues, first on IOS it gives an error 500 and next in Android as the navigation is not cancelled, I have a not found error and going back to the app after the call.
I read that `args.cancel=true` is the way to go but the variable doesn't seem to exist no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you can use the `Xamarin.Essentials: Phone Dialer` to open the telephone number. Furthermore you need to test on the physical device for the ios, because the ios simulator can't call number and will throw an exception.

1. Open the AndroidManifest.xml file under the Properties folder and add the following inside of the manifest node:

   ```
   <queries>
     <intent>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
       <data android:scheme="tel"/>
    </intent>
   </queries>
   ```
2. Use the following code:

   ```
    public void WebViewNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs args)
   {
       if (args.Url.StartsWith("tel:"))
       {
           string number = args.Url.Split(':')[1];
           Xamarin.Essentials.PhoneDialer.Open(number);
           args.Cancel = true;
       }
   }
   ```

In adition, you can also use the custom renderer to do that, for more information, you can check my answer in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73274034/how-can-i-redirect-the-phone-dialer-from-webview-when-i-click-on-a-phone-number/73274071#73274071).

Comment: I'm already testing on a physical device for IOS... args.Cancel doesn't exist (you wrote "arg" without an "s" but I think it's a mistake.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, but I have tested it and `args.Cancel` worked. @Entretoize

Comment: I run the code on both android and ios device, worked well. The navigating will be canceled and the phone dialer will be opened. @Entretoize

Comment: I have version 5.0.0.2515 that is the ast version I can get : https://youtu.be/N5c-5HUcOoA and Cancel doesn't exist :-( I also have VS2022 and it is up to date

Comment: Oh, I find it. It should be `WebNavigatingEventArgs args` not `WebNavigatedEventArgs args`. @Entretoize

Comment: When I posted the answer, I just used the code in your question instead of the code in my project, sorry for my mistake. @Entretoize

Comment: Oh yes ! Stupid copy/paste from myself from "onnavigated" code... thank you !